# How to manually execute a function inside a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.plugin_name = function(options) {

        var $this = $(this);

        var defaults = {
            // some defaults
        };

        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var work = {
            action_1: function() {
                // do something
            },
            action_2: function(output) {
                alert('hello world');
            }
        }

        that.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            work.action_1();
        });

        return $this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

It's being used like any traditional jquery plugin, by being attached to a page element like so:

```
$('#search-form').plugin_name({
    // overide options
});
```

My question is, how can I execute the `work.action_2()` function that's deeply nested inside the plugin? I would like to call it manually from the javascript console in firebug.

Comment: You recommend that you start by following the plugin authoring guidelines (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: By the way, you have no `that` declared in the code, did you mean `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, how can I execute the work.action_2() function that's deeply nested inside the plugin?

**You can't, it's outside of your scope!**

you can't reach private function variables, just like you can't reach my functions...

Comment: I figured this was the issue, only reason why I needed this was because I am making a call to one of the google apis and they accept a callback function as one of the parameters. Google only recognizes this function if it's in the global sphere. If I put that function outside the plugin then I can't use the plugin's options :(

Comment: @JakeRow123. You can define it the the global scope, and call it with the `options` values. Simple isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Create it in a separate utility function if its needed independently, better if its in your own global object.
So you can call it like so: $.myGlobalObj.action_2()